# Duplicate entry [...] for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, oxid

I am facing a weird behaviour regarding updating the table `oxseo` in an oxid eshop 4.7.

The table `oxseo` has following schema:

```
+------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| OXOBJECTID | OXIDENT | OXSHOPID | OXLANGID | OXSTDURL | OXSEOURL | [...] |
+------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
```

and has a PRIMARY (*that's also the keyname*) key on the fields:

```
+---------+----------+--------+
| OXIDENT | OXSHOPID | OXLANG |
+---------+----------+--------+
```

and I try to execute following sql (*replaced real values with dummy data*) via the linux shell:

```
UPDATE oxseo
SET
  OXIDENT = "8e4b0ac7[...]",
  OXSEOURL = "my/seo/url/"
WHERE
  OXOBJECTID = "123"`
```

which leads to the error:

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '8e4b0ac7[...]-oxbaseshop-0' for key 'PRIMARY'`

However, when looking for the string `8e4b0ac7[...]` in the whole table using the phpMyAdmin there is no row returned. Despite that I have checked manually using

```
SELECT * FROM field1 = hash
SELECT * FROM field2 = hash
```

and so on.

Anyone has an idea what the cause could be?

Comment: why you set UNIQUE key on filed OXIDENT

Comment: @DhavalBhavsar Thanks for your back-question. It's defined by the OXID eShop developers. I have no influence on that. Despite that, to answer to your question at least partly: `OXIDENT` is an md5 hash of `OXSEOURL` which identifies the record/seo url in some way.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? Whoever did this, what did I do wrong?

Comment: How many rows have `OXOBJECTID = "123" ` and what is the output of `show create table oxseo ` Please learn how to show a schema, not whatever you are trying to show in the top 20% of your question. Look around at db questions here.

Comment: @Drew & fthiella  Thanks for the head up. I will improve my upcoming questions as recommend. Regarding your question: How many rows have `OXOBJECTID = "123"`. I receive two rows and I am pretty sure here's the issue. Give me a moment. I will check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple. Whatever that update statement is attempting to do would leave the table in a state with duplicate entries (2 or more rows) in the PRIMARY key as seen in the output from `show create table oxseo`.

That PRIMARY key may be on a single column, or it may be a composite (multi-column) key.

The db engine forbids it, because the schema forbids it.

Comment: That's the point. I have extended the `update` statement. `UPDATE oxseo SET OXIDENT = '[...]', OXSEOURL = '[...]' WHERE OXOBJECTID = '[...]' AND OXSTDURL = '[...]' AND OXSEOURL = '[...]'` It works now.